# Convert an int bitmask to string

Tags: php, bitmask

I am trying to find out what flags has been set a cookie. `http/Cookie` does the job but returns a bitmask.

How can i convert the bitmask to string so that i can know what flags(such as httponly and secure) has been set in the cookie

https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Cookie/getFlags

Comment: there's only two bitflags, and they're provided as constants: `SECURE` and `HTTPONLY`. should be easy enough to `|` and `&` those constants against the `getFlags()` returned int...

Comment: @MarcB yes you are right but it takes time , i believe there must be a better way that doing it manually

Comment: not really. there's nothing in that class to do this,s o you'll have to do it yourself. there's no general "int to bitmask" function in php, other than taking an int and converting it to a "binary string" e.g. `(int)42 -> (str)'00101010'`

Comment: Do you mean [decbin()](http://php.net/decbin)?